# Refreshing for external database changes when using sqlalchemy, flask on new http request

Tags: python, rest, flask, sqlalchemy

I am developing an API that returns JSONs using Flask, Sqlalchemy and a MySQL db that is used by an external application. The issue is that on a new request for data to the API I am building, the data returned using the following code is old (new entries added from external client after the api was started are not shown):

area/routes.py:

```
from app.db import Base, session
from app.db.models import Room, Entry
@areas_bp.route('/area/<int:area_id>')
def area(area_id):
    '''
    Return all rooms in area and their entries
    :param area_id: id of an area
    :return:
    '''

    rooms = session.query(Room).filter_by(lsb_area_id=area_id)
    entries = session.query(Entry)

    session.rollback()

    ret_list = list()

    for room in rooms:
        entries_filtered = entries.filter_by(room_id=room.id)

        # ret_str += f"Room {room.id} '{room.room_name}' <br />"
        room_dict = room.to_dict()
        room_dict['entries'] = [simplify_area_dict(entry.to_dict()) for entry in entries_filtered]

        ret_list.append(room_dict)

    return jsonify(ret_list)
```

As you can see, I have added session.rollback() which seems to update the data in the session, but I am not sure if that is the efficient way to achieve this.
I also read about scoped_session, but I am not sure if it will help me in any way as well.
Can you point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

database setup (app.db):

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
from os.path import abspath

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session


def read_db_config(filename='app/db/config.ini', section='mysql'):
    """ Read database configuration file and return a dictionary object
    :param filename: name of the configuration file
    :param section: section of database configuration
    :return: a dictionary of database parameters
    """
    # create parser and read ini configuration file
    parser = ConfigParser()
    parser.read(filename)

    # get section, default to mysql
    db = {}
    if parser.has_section(section):
        items = parser.items(section)
        for item in items:
            db[item[0]] = item[1]
    else:
        raise Exception('[MySQL] {0} not found in the {1} file. Abs filename: {2}'.format(section, filename, abspath(filename)))

    return db


db_config = read_db_config()

# SqlAlchemy Database Configuration With Mysql
db_uri = f"mysql+pymysql://{ db_config['user'] }:{ db_config['password'] }@" \
                                        f"{ db_config['host'] }:{ db_config['port'] }/" \
                                        f"{ db_config['database'] }"
engine = create_engine(db_uri)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)
session = scoped_session(SessionLocal)

Base = declarative_base()
metadata = Base.metadata
```

Comment: Use the [Flask-SQLAlchemy](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/) extension. It will take care of your scoped session for you.

Comment: I read on stockoverflow and other places, that it is better to use the native sqlalchemy because it allows to be used in any python method in the app, not only in flask routes. I might have misunderstood, but that was the reason I changed from flask-sqlalchemy to sqlalchemy.

Comment: Where did you read that? My guess is that it came from a straw man argument in a blog post because it's certainly not true. I do it occasionally when debugging or performing a complex migration. Regardless, it's up to you whether you think Flask-SQLAlchemy is worth using for your use case. SQLAlchemy [actually recommends](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_basics.html#when-do-i-construct-a-session-when-do-i-commit-it-and-when-do-i-close-it) using Flask-Sqlachemy

Comment: Yeah, one of them was this - https://towardsdatascience.com/use-flask-and-sqlalchemy-not-flask-sqlalchemy-5a64fafe22a4

Comment: If you are referencing the section titled "Loading data outside of the app", I can assure you they are incorrect. I wrote a script today to populate my database with sample data for debugging. It was very easy. 3 lines of boilerplate before I started creating objects.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the information! I will try to see if it makes things easier. :)